getting error "Application not found" whenever i restart my django app on cpanel
Am trying to set up my django app in c-panel but facing a certain. Whenever i restart the app, Am getting the below error
No such application (or application not configured)

And whenever i edit the app config and click save i get the below error
Error
KeyError: 'Config does not contain directory: mutoconsults.kimdigitary.com/muto-consults'

Below is my app configuration, and cpanel shows my app is already running.

And if i navigate to the domain name i get the below info
it works python 3.9

